# Android - AlphaAnimation - FadeOut ImageView than FadeIn other ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, fadein, fadeout

I have a logo on my page, with a certain event I would like to make an error image appear instead of the logo, which goes to FadeOut and then the logo reappears in FadeIn

```
  val errorDrawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.error)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable)

        val errorFadeOut = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)
        errorFadeOut.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
        errorFadeOut.duration = 2000

        errorFadeOut.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                imageView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {

            }
        })
        imageView.startAnimation(errorFadeOut)

        val logoFadeIn = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f)
        logoFadeIn.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        logoFadeIn.startOffset = 2000
        logoFadeIn.duration = 1000

        val logoDrawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.logo)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(logoDrawable)

        logoFadeIn.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

        })
        imageView.startAnimation(logoFadeIn)
```

In my case, with this code, the problem is that the error logo that should go to fadeOut is never displayed (while the original logo that goes to FadeIn later works)

If I removed the second animation, the first one is displayed correctly. It would seem that together, one after the other, only the second is taken (or that the second "overwrites" the first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use glide.
u can animate change with it and do a lots of work with images

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'


    DrawableCrossFadeFactory factory =
            new DrawableCrossFadeFactory.Builder().setCrossFadeEnabled(true).build();


Glide.with(java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
.load(R.drawable.logo)
.transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
.into(imageView)
```

use this code

```
 val factory: DrawableCrossFadeFactory =
            DrawableCrossFadeFactory.Builder().setCrossFadeEnabled(true).build()

if(error){
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.error)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
            .into(imageView)

}else{
      Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.logo)
         .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
         .skipMemoryCache(true)
         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
         .into(imageView)

}
```

Comment: In your case you are uploading only one image, in my case I have 2 images, the initial logo, the error logo to be put in FadeOut and the original logo to be put back in FadeIn

Comment: @AdamoBranz so u can use this code again for second image, and it witll change with animation. put your error logo in .load()

Comment: @AdamoBranz just copy last part of the code, (Glide.with ...)

Comment: Even with Glide I always have the problem I found with AlphaAnimator: IF I put 2 animations only the second one is displayed

Comment: @AdamoBranz this problem with glide ?!
i dont have this problem with it
you should handle this .
its so easy and powerfull library

Comment: I didn't say Glide is not going well. I just said that even with Glide I can't do 2 Animations one after the other because it would only do the second

Comment: Solved with this

Comment: @AdamoBranz please check the answer as correct answer
tnx.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the only solution that comes close to the required result is this:

```
 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            val factory: DrawableCrossFadeFactory =
                DrawableCrossFadeFactory.Builder(800).setCrossFadeEnabled(true).build()

            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.logo)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .into(imageView)
        }, 400)
```

I immediately set the error image, then I have to make a handler (otherwise the error image would not be displayed), and inside the handler with Glide reload the logo image

Answer (score 0):

or, better :

```
  val factory: DrawableCrossFadeFactory =
            DrawableCrossFadeFactory.Builder(800).setCrossFadeEnabled(true).build()

        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.error)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
            .into(imageView)

        Handler().postDelayed({

            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.logo)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(factory))
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .into(imageView)
        }, 800)
```

Also in this case the second animation must be done inside a handler otherwise the first one is not displayed